# Oracle Apex 5 drag&drop between two reports

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, drag-and-drop, oracle-apex

I'm trying to build a drag&drop feature between two classic reports in Oracle APEX. But I can only drag in one report and can't drop it in the other report.

At the loading of the page I have this code:

```html
$(".draggable_emp").draggable({
  "containment": "window",
  "helper":      "clone",
  "revert":      "invalid"
});
```

ALthough there is window, my drag stays in the first report.

Can someone help me?

Thanks,

Karsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also use the droppable api to allow the report(s) to accept the draggable objects.

Add the droppable library to your app / page: `#IMAGE_PREFIX#libraries/jquery-ui/1.10.4/ui/minified/jquery.ui.droppable.min.js`

Then make the required regions droppable.  The way I do it is add a class to the relevant regions and then accept that class with the droppable accept option.  You can also use a hidden item to keep track of which items are held in which report and use that to do the update on submit, if one is required.